# How to check if an index is already occupied?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm developing a board game program using 2D array. Because in board games you can place your stone into a cell that already has a stone in it. Is there a way in Java to check if an index is already occupied? For example,

```
int[][] board = new int[5][5];
```

I want to check if the user or the program already chose `cell [1][3]`, and use a while loop to tell the user to choose another cell that hasn't been chosen?

Comment: Mark all cells with special value if you can, -1 for example. And then just check if board[1][3] == -1, if so, it's free otherwise it's taken.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an object with a boolean attribute and create an Array with it.
example:

```
public class myField{
    private bool chosen = false;
    private ... 
    ....
}
```

Usage:

```
public class main{
    private myField[][] board = new myField[5][5];
    ....
}
```

Checking if occupied:

```
if(board[1][3].chosen == true)
{
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: gotta make a getter for `chosen `, or set it to `public`

Comment: i know. I just wanted to save time.

Comment: You could just make boolean chosen[5][5] and mark all of them false at the beginning.

Comment: The default value for `boolean` variables is `false`, so a boolean array would be automatically initialized correctly.

Comment: yeah but you could additional infos with an Object (like figures on it, if the field triggers an action, if it adds coins to the player on field... Mario party :D)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this little Java Sample [Chess Applet](http://www.trinimon.de/Chess/ChessGame/Develop/chess10src.htm). It uses value `0` for empty squares and `1` for border fields. This simplifies the out of border check as well. The board has a size of 10x12 fields.

Other values represent roughly the material value - positive values for white, negative for black. So the balance is `0` if both opponents have the same pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Java initialises arrays of objects to null, ints to 0, floats to 0.0 and booleans to false, so you could just check if the index equals 0. i.e

```
if(board[x][y]==0){
//set piece
}else{
//handle already occupied case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a cell that is not used, for example:

```
boolean[][] initMap(int x, int y) {
   boolean[][] result = new boolean[x][y];
}

boolean isOccupied(int[][] map, int x, int y) {
  return map[x][y]; 
}

boolean putARock(boolean[][] map, int x, int y) {
   if(isOccupied(map)) {
      map[x][y] = true;
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   } 
}

/* somewhere in main or GUI code */

boolean[][] map = initMap(x,y);

boolean isPuttingDone = false;

do {
  isPuttingDone = putARock(map, getXFromKeyboard(), getYFromKeyboard());
} while (!isPuttingDone);
```

You have to write a right methods to get X and Y from user input (or you can do it differently). This is not really OO code though.